# Finding Invalid Geometry using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

While trying to clip a layer with another polygon layer, I received the message that it contained invalid geometries. I used the Topology Checker tool under Vector/Topology Checker and it confirmed that there was a geometry error, but it only indicated which feature contained the error. It did not show what or where the error was. I tried using the Check Geometries tool under Vector/Geometry Tools and tried checking various options but could not find the error. One of the options kept crashing QGIS. I then tried the Check Validity tool under Vector/Geometry Tools (there were two Geometry Tools under Vector for some reason, and and it was under the 2nd Geometry Tools). When I ran it, it kept giving an error "-2147483645 See log for more detail" but this message was in the log so I don't know what it means. Here is a link to the shapefile:
http://brucewiland.com/download/invalid_geometry.zip

Can anyone tell me what the invalid geometry is and if there is a better tool to find it?

Using QGIS 2.18.18

Comment: https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/bad-bad-polygon-fixing-invalid-geometries-with-quantum-gis/ might illuminate some suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS 3.2. you have a tool called "**fix geometries**". 
You will not know where was the error, but it will fix it.

Comment: A screen grab showing where would be helpful. I can't find such a tool...

Comment: @Auspex You will find this tool in the toolbox (menu "Processing" or Ctrl+alt+T). in the "Search bar", just type "Fix" or look in the categorie "Vector geometry"

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I was looking in all the Tools under **Vector**.

Answer (score 3):

That error is likely due to the shapefile being of geometry type `wkbPolygon25D` which you can see if you check the metadata by *right-clicking* the layer and going to `Properties > Metadata`. It would say something like:

> Geometry type of the features in this layer
>
> Polygon (WKB type: "PolygonZ")

If you type the following in the **Python Console**, you can see the same value which arises from the error log (which is probably stating without words that it cannot run the tool on geometries with a z-dimension):

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr.wkbPolygon25D

>>> -2147483645
```

---

A simple fix is to re-save the layer as polygon layer **without** the z-dimension:

[image: Save as polygon]

The geometries should no longer contain any errors in the newly-saved shapefile.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue last time. I used both mentioned tools but nothing worked. My solution was to import the shapefile into a postgis database and use the functions

```
ST_isValid(geom)
```

and

```
ST_IsValidReason(geom);
```

it helped me to find the reason.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate all of the suggestions. Re-saving without a z-dimension did not solve the problem. I did not try the postgis database suggestion because I was not sure how to do it. I decided I didn't need to know why the geometries were invalid, so I downloaded and installed QGIS 3.2 and used the "fix geometries"  tool. Like magic it fixed the problem.